# Windows Mobile: Radio button not available in WM 6.0 Standard SDK using C#?

Tags: windows-mobile

I am developing a Windows Mobile application for Standard 6.0 SDK on C# language. I tried to add Radio button control in my application screen. But i am not finding any Radio button control in Tool box in this sdk? Doesn't it have? Is it possible to create using some other way?

Appreciate your help on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Radio buttons and buttons in general aren't included in the standard (smartphone) sdk. The reason for this is that use of these controls violates Microsoft's UI recommendations for smartphones. To overcome this issue you could create your own control that mimics radio button's behaviour. However, it will be better to consider an alternative. Radio buttons are hard to use in a thumb operated device.

Comment: Thank you very much. What do you suggest to use when i my application screen needs to have such control ( list all the items but only one item can be selectable)?

Comment: As I've said you need to create your own control. Extend the Control class and override the OnPaint method. You could also create a User Control . I believe that a good way to do this will be to use a menu. Display all items with the current selection being checked.

Comment: Doesn't a list box list all items and let you select one?